# detecting reason for slow LAN

Tags: lan, measurement, network-traffic

hi we're having a small company LAN with about 10 boxes and a wireless webcam. the problem is that internet + lan is really slow and i'd like to find out which client is causing it.
is there a tool which can measure my client's traffic?
thanks

Comment: What is the network speed of the network cards? How are the computers connected, are you using a hub or a switch? Why do you feel that it is slow, how do you measure it atm?

Comment: it should be 100mbit - the computers are connected via switch.
i'm having fast dsl but browsing feels like isdn :/ no measurement tool yet.

Comment: What do you mean by the LAN is slow?  Do you mean when browsing the network shares, file transfers, or both?  Workgroup or domain?

Answer (score 0):

Have you measured the actual DSL speed?  [Speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) has tools and there are many others.  Possibly bad ADSL connection?  Check the port with the modem connected and look for errors.  Check that the modem and the switch or router are set to a specific speed and dulpes and that both devices are teh same for speed and duplex.  You may need to experiment with this or your ISP may be able to advise you..  I have seen Auto/Auto fail many times and cause many dropped packets.